# How to call custom community page in visualforce page in Salesforce

Tags: development-environment

I want to call custom community page URL from my custom Visualforce page. My VF page having one Terms and condition custom label where i have used Href tag for redirecting form VF Page to Community pages.But somehow it is opening login flow Url not in community page Url.

Because my Visual force page is called in Login flow of salesforce.

So can any one please help on this to how to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance